# Can having multiple answers on a single question have any effect on the Sportsmanship badge?

Tags: support, badges

After I already answered a question, I have button to add another answer.

If I add another answer and both are voted up, will my answer(s) be added to count of [Sportsmanship badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68137/voting-for-competing-answers-sportsmanship-badge/68156)? Once or twice?

**EDIT**

I can't vote up on my answers so suppose there's also a third answer which I vote up.

> The badge logic is:
>
> 1. your answer has a positive score
> 2. your answer isn't deleted
> 3. you vote on a competing answer

Comment: Wow this is a nice one. I guess it all depends on the definition of a "competing answer". technically two answers you post are still competing answers but I'll bet you're supposed to assume competing means "someone else's".

Comment: Well.... you can't vote on your own content, so there needs to be a third answer there so that you can vote on it..... but yeah, good question as if it counts as one or 2....

Comment: A dev would need to confirm the exact logic but I'll be surprised if it wasn't just once. The badge is awarded if you have *any* answer that's positively scored and upvote an answer by *a different user* on **the same question**. So the count is the number of **questions** where you've met the criteria - not the number of answers that have contributed towards it.

Comment: @JonClements actually, I'm pretty sure you can have two notches towards the badge from the same question if there are two competing answers you upvote. So I think it's like this: the count is the number of answers you upvoted _as long as you have an upvoted competing answer of your own_.

Comment: @AndrasDeak I know - Glorfindel's clarified that in his answer, however, I'm not the only one surprised that's the case - see comments on that answer...

Comment: @Jon yeah, sorry, I just read that comment thread :) I'll just leave my original comment here anyway for visibility.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I justed tested this on [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/268222/70594) on our sister site [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net). I have [three](https://mathoverflow.net/a/268233/70594) [upvoted](https://mathoverflow.net/a/268235/70594) [answers](https://mathoverflow.net/a/268239/70594) there (they're wiki posts, but that doesn't matter); I upvoted one of the answers but my progress towards the Sportsmanship badge increased just by one:

[image]

**But**, after upvoting *another* answer, I now have a progress of two:

[image]

As @Oleg notes in the comments, this is not because I have multiple upvoted answers on that question; it would have worked *even if I had just a single answer on that question* (I just tested this on another site). I'm not sure this is intended behaviour; that would mean that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33733753/4751173) alone already enables me for 28% of the badge.

I'll update the [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67397/295232) on Meta Stack Exchange to reflect this.

Comment: I saw the same with only one answer. So you can get multiple points for one question if you upvote multiple other answers but it doesn't matter if you have one answer or more.

Comment: Well well well TIL... I'm still really quite surprised though. I really thought sportsmanship was more along the lines of after you've answered N many questions and *with consideration* voted up a competing answer on it then you're being sporty over time and that's good behaviour which badges are designed to be awarded for. The fact you can fast-forward it by getting an upvoted answer, then just blitzing every other answer with upvotes (worthy or not and potentially preventing answer deletion) is skewing the voting system and is behaviour that we **don't** want encouraged...

Comment: @JonClements exactly my thoughts. Of course, the badge system can't distinguish between votes *with consideration* and 'gaming the system' votes, but the 1-per-question cap makes a lot of sense.

Comment: @Glorfindel yeah... that's the illusion I've been running under for over 5 years of how it worked :) (and how I think it **should** work - but - cat's out the bag and suggesting a change now would be pointless)

Comment: Yeah, I expect a [feature-request] about this to be [status-declined-for-historical-reasons], that's why I'm not opening one.